# AWS Amplify & React Submit Form Data - message: "Not Authorized to access createRecipe on type Mutation"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have set up an React/AWS amplify project. I have managed to add some data into DynamoDB from in AWS, but if I try to submit some form data from my React App, I am getting this error coming back from the API.

I'm not sure what to do.. I am logged in as a user. my Auth Rules on my graphQL are as follows. I want to allow public to see all data, but users to be able to create, read, update, delete. Any help would be great. I followed the AWS auths rules.. but it doesn't seem to let me add to the database.

Some Screenshots are below. Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaIaI.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmO1G.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gqh4.png

Answer (score 2):

One thing you may want to check is the `Settings` in AWS AppSync to validate what your `Default authorization mode` is set to. I had a similar issue recently in my vue project and it turned out that my API key had expired. I changed the expiry on the API key and validated the key was still the same key in my `aws-exports.js` file and it started working again.

Comment: I actually figured out what I missed, my api wasn't set to Cognito for the Primary auth mode it was set to API key, I changed that and it worked. now I'm trying to figure out how you have public access to the site without having to sign in, but if you want to create a recipe you have to login.. as the moment, you have to login to see the page.